# Segfault on cat/waitpid (Execve in C)

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault, ctrl, waitpid

My friends and I are trying to code a shell.
My problem is that running 'cat' command and then exit STDIN with ^C makes my program segfault on waitpid and so quit my program... (What I don't want of course !)

Every command is working perfectly and I don/t have any other problems... I'm just asking about it adn how to resolve these (big) problem.

Thank you for your help guys !
See my code for executing commands just below:

```
static int      cmd_executeit(char **env, t_shell *shell, char *path)
{
    pid_t   forked;
    int     ret;

    ret = 0;
    if ((forked = fork()) == FAILURE)
        return (bi_error(shell, "I can't fork with you :("));
    if (forked == SUCCESS)
    {
         if (execve(path, shell->cmd, env) == FAILURE)
            return (bi_error(shell, "Execution of the command failed"));
    }
    else
    {
        if (waitpid(forked, &ret, 0) < 0)
            return (bi_error(shell, "I can't wait for this command. Sorry."));
    }
    if (WIFEXITED(ret) && (WEXITSTATUS(ret) == SUCCESS))
        return (SUCCESS);
    return (FAILURE);
}
```

I got the answer, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to catch the signal... I'm stupid :).

For any explanations:
We were creating a shell, and we were using termcaps for line editing. And before, we caught ^C to avoid to quit the program and re-print Prompt. So when we launched an executable like bc, or, cat, who's reading STDIN and we presses ^C, we were reprinting the prompt but executable didn't quit (cat yes, but bc no).
So first, we were restoring termcaps before executing commands and there were the problem above :P.
It was segfaulting, so we just caught SIGINT, restoring our termcaps, and reprinting prompt. It works perfectly now :).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.